# Can't install spock to grails 1.3.7 project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spock

I created a simple hello world grails app using Grails 1.3.7:

```
grails create-app hello
grails create-controller hello
```

Then I try to install the spock plugin using:

```
grails install-plugin spock
```

And I get the following:

```
Error loading event script from file [/Users/wholladay/.grails/1.3.7/projects/hello/plugins/spock-0.6/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/Users/wholladay/.ivy2/cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.6-groovy-1.8.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.6.0-groovy-1.8 is not compatible with Groovy 1.7.8. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org
Spock location: file:/Users/wholladay/.ivy2/cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.6-groovy-1.8.jar
Groovy location: file:/usr/local/Cellar/grails/current/lib/groovy-all-1.7.8.jar
```

So I went to: http://versioninfo.spockframework.org and noticed that there is a version 0.6-groovy-1.7 of spock. So I tried:

```
grails install-plugin spock 0.6-groovy-1.7
```

But then I got the following error:

```
Error resolving plugin [name:spock, group:org.grails.plugins, version:0.6-groovy-1.7].
```

Plugin not found for name [spock] and version [0.6-groovy-1.7]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the dependency resolution install instructions on the [plugin page?](http://grails.org/plugin/spock)
In your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.6-groovy-1.7"
  }
  plugins {
    test(":spock:0.6") {
      exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! all I had to do was read the documentation?! That is awesome, thanks for bringing this to my attention. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made simple mistake. What you want is:

```
grails install-plugin spock 0.6-groovy-1.7
```

Comment: Yes, I did make a typo the second time I tried this. However, I just re-tried it with "spock" and got the same result. I updated my question to reflect this.